# Saving Object record through Lightning

Tags: lightning, aura

I'm trying below example which is giving ERROR as response. Any idea on how to get the below code execution successfully:

```
Component:
<aura:component controller="ConCreation">
    <aura:attribute name="conInfo" type="Contact" default="{'sObject':'conatct','LastName':''}"/>
      <ui:inputText aura:id="LastName" label="Last Name"
                    value="{!v.conInfo.LastName}"
                    required="true"/>

      <ui:inputText aura:id="FirstName" label="First Name"
                    value="{!v.conInfo.FirstName}"
                    required="true"/>    
    <ui:button press="{!c.saveCon}" label="click"/>    
</aura:component>
```

Aura controller:

```
({
    saveCon : function(component, event) {
        var con = component.get("v.conInfo");

        var action1 = component.get("c.saveContact");
        action1.setParams({
        "c": con
       });
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state--'+state);            
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.conInfo", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);       
    }
})
```

Aura apex Class:

```
global with sharing class ConCreation{
    @auraenabled
    public static string saveContact(contact c){
        if(c != null)
        {
            insert c;
            system.debug('c--'+c);
        }
        return c.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: What error message are you facing?

Comment: I'm getting 'Error' in response of java script controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace `sObject` in your default with `sobjectType` as it is the only way the sobject will be recognised in the controller.

Also, you return the id of the contact in your apex classes and set it as a the v.ConInfo which changes the type of the aura attribute and prevent any use after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

You have to pass function parameter value in String format then deserialize them;

In the component controller pass string instead of a JavaScript object:

```
action1.setParams({
    "c": JSON.stringify(con)
});
```

Then in Apex deserialize the string

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id saveContact(String c) {
    Contact con = (Contact) Json.deserialize(c, Contact.class);
    System.debug(con);
    if(con != null){
        insert con;
        return con.Id;           
    }
    return null;
}
```